# How to Read Specific Information in CSV File

Tags: c, csv

```
Number of Spaces,10,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
Type,Set Id,Intraset Id,Name,Property Cost,House Cost,Hotel Cost,Rent,Rent with House,Rent With Hotel
Go,400,MU,,,,,,,
Property,0,0,Kemper A,500,50,50,5,50,2000
Property,0,1,Kemper B,1000,50,50,10,75,2500
Property,1,0,Bainer A,2000,200,200,20,100,3000
Property,1,1,Bainer B,2500,200,200,25,150,3000
Property,1,2,Bainer C,3000,200,200,30,200,3500
Property,2,0,SocialSci A,4000,400,400,40,300,4000
Property,2,1,SocialSci B,4500,400,400,45,400,4000
Property,2,2,SocialSci C,5000,400,400,50,500,4000
Property,2,3,SocialSci D,5500,400,400,55,600,4500
```

How would I go about finding specific parts of the CSV file? I only need `0,0,Kemper A,500,50,50,5,50,2000` etc. all the values for each property.
What I have been doing is

```
fscanf(file,"Number of Spaces,%d",&b->numSpaces);
fscanf(file,"Go,%d",&b->goValue);
```

but this seems inefficient/each board is different and there isn't a set amount of properties. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

*Answered keeping in mind the language `C`*

No this won't work as you have seen already. The way would be to use `fgets()` to read the file line by line and then parse it. That would be a choice here. With your way of scanning the first `scanf` would be successful and then the latter one wouldn't be. Then the those `,,,,` will stay in the stream making your successive calls to `scanf` not work as you would expect it to.

The solution I was talking about - use `fgets` and then try to find the occurence the word `"Go"` and once you find it then on this line, after trimming white-space at the end and beginning of line and if you know that format would be always `Go,400,MU,,,,,,,` then you would use `strtok` to parse and get the inputs. On case when you need conversion from string to `int` you can use `strtol`(for `float/double` use `strtod` or `strtof`) function

Also in case you want yourself to be free from all these parsing and processing, look for some parsing library (`csv` parser - don't ask which one), there are plenty of those.