# Reading a csv file to a struct in C

Tags: c, string, csv, struct

The csv files will all have the following format:

```
Number of Spaces,10,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
Type,Set Id,Intraset Id,Name,Property Cost,House Cost,Hotel Cost,Rent,Rent with House,Rent With Hotel
Go,400,MU,,,,,,,
Property,0,0,0A,500,50,50,5,50,2000
Property,0,1,0B,1000,50,50,10,75,2500
Property,1,0,1A,2000,200,200,20,100,3000
Property,1,1,1B,2500,200,200,25,150,3000
Property,1,2,1C,3000,200,200,30,200,3500
Property,2,0,2A,4000,400,400,40,300,4000
Property,2,1,2B,4500,400,400,45,400,4000
Property,2,2,2C,5000,400,400,50,500,4000
Property,2,3,2D,5500,400,400,55,600,4500
```

The fourth line describes what each field in the lines below it are i.e. for line 5, type is property, set id is 0, name is 0A, etc. I have a struct `Space` that contains variables for all this information. The 5th line is special: it has type Go, get $400 for passing Go, name is MU, and none of the other fields apply. (This is a version of Monopoly).

Where I'm struggling is how to get the values that I need. So far I have only managed to get the number of spaces value (this determines the number of rows on the board) with this:

```
void openSpecs(char *fileName) {
  FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");

  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open %s\n", fileName);
  }

  char c;

  do {
    fscanf(file, "%c", &c);
    //printf("%c", c);
  } while (!feof(file) && c != ',');


  //printf("\n\n");
  int numSpaces;
  fscanf(file, "%d", &numSpaces);
  //printf("there are %d spaces\n", numSpaces);
// note: the printf statements are there to help me see where I'm at in the file

  fclose(file);
}
```

I'm conflicted on how to approach the rest of the file. I'm thinking of using a `while` loop to just skip the rest of the commas, and then just reading through line 4, as I don't need to save any of that. From there, I'm not sure what to do. If I use `strtok`, I need to have a line from the file already as a C string, correct? I can't statically allocate a C string and then use `fscanf` (no static allocation allowed), so how do I dynamically allocate for a string whose length is unknown?

Edit:

```
char str[4096];
  fgets(str, 4096, file);
  printf("%s\n", str);

  int goCash = 0;
  char* name = NULL;

  char delim[2] = ",";
  char* token;
  token = strtok(str, delim); // this is Go


  token = strtok(str, delim);
  goCash = (int) token;


  token = strtok(str, delim);
  strcpy(name, token);


  printf("you get %d for going past %s\n", goCash, name);
```

Comment: You should most certainly look at [How to Read Specific Information in CSV File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363933/how-to-read-specific-information-in-csv-file) since the data is formatted almost the same way.  The heading information seems to be on the fourth line, not the third.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for linking that question. However, I still don't understand how fgets would work in this case. If I understand correctly, fgets takes 3 parameters: char* str, int n, FILE* file. Since the length of each line in the file is unknown and we can't just set a max value of 100 for the str length, how would I allocate space for the line?

Comment: What is the longest conceivable length for each field?  What is the maximum number of fields?  Is the product bigger than 4096?  I'd either use standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) with a buffer size of 4096 (or smaller if you're sure that you can get away with it), or use POSIX
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) — or a private implementation of it — which allocates space as needed.  Gut feel: `fgets()` with 4096 is OK for you. I probably wouldn't even check for overlong lines — GIGO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that makes sense. I apologize - but I have another question. I got the 5th line in the file (Go, 400, MU,,,,,,,) using fgets, and now I'm trying to use strtok with ',' as my delimiter. I am able to break them up into 3 tokens and print them out on separate lines; however, when I try to assign 400 to an int and MU to a char* I am getting undefined behavior. I put the code I just wrote in the original post, but I'm not sure how to successfully convert.

Comment: Use `sscanf()` or `atoi()` or `strtol()` or … there are a myriad ways to convert a string into a number.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful as `strtok` could run in to problems.

For example, consider the the following lines:

```
Property,0,0,0A,500,50,50,5,50,2000
Property,,0,0A,500,50,50,5,50,2000
```

Note that in the second line, the second field is missing and you have two consecutive delimiters: `",,"`. `strtok` doesn't give you any indication that there was a field missing, it just skips to the next available field.

You can fix this by replacing the occurrences of `,,` with `, ,`

Another issue is that `fgets` includes the end of line character and you want to remove that.

```
enum { Type, SetId, IntrasetId, Name, PropertyCost, HouseCost, HotelCost,
    Rent, RentwithHouse, RentWithHotel, total };

FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
char buf[1000], temp[1000];
while(fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fp))
{
    //remove end of line
    temp[strcspn(temp, "\r\n")] = 0;

    //replace ",," with ", ,"
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0, len = strlen(temp); i < len; i++) 
    {
        buf[j++] = temp[i];
        if (temp[i]==',' && temp[i+1]==',')
            buf[j++] = '0';
    }
    buf[j] = 0;

    //read all the fields
    char field[total][100];
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) *field[i] = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char *ptr = strtok(buf, ",");
    while(ptr)
    {
        strcpy(field[i++], ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        printf("%s, ", field[i]);
    printf(" rent(%d)\n", atoi(field[RentWithHotel]));
}
fclose(fp);
```